# Google Puppeteer - Can't intercept PLAIN request type?

Tags: puppeteer

Trying to use Google Puppeteer to intercept requests, but it seems to completely ignore "plain" type requests that aren't images, js, xhr, etc.

Is this a gap in Google Puppeteer? I'm not seeing anything in the docs about it.

Comment: Can you provide a small example that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The request type is inconsistent; puppeteer will show something as 'other' but network inspector in a real Chrome window will show "text/plain", while Firefox shows "plain" (which I assume is shorthand for "text/plain".)
- The site I was trying to scrape is not hosted so I was trying to find a public site with the same problem. Could not find one. Not sure why the requests are not happening with puppeteer and/or it's not intercepting them. Maybe the javascript making the request is behaving different in puppeteer.
- In the end I was able to reconstruct the information I was trying to scrape through other means.